# Checking functor in a list

Tags: list, prolog, functor

If I have this:

```
?:check_dv([v(1,x),v(2,y)], X).
```

How can I check what is the second argument in, for example `v(1,x)` (in this case `x`)?

Once I have the head of the list: `[Head | Tail]`, with `Head = [v(1,x)]`, how can I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that all elements are of the form `v(_,_)`, then you can simply use **unification**:

```
Head = v(_, x)
```

This succeeds **iff** `Head` is of this form, and works correctly in all directions.

If the elements of the list are not so homogenous, you can use **`arg/3`**:

```
arg(2, Head, x)
```

Note that this only works if `Head` is sufficiently **instantiated**, and is for this reason alone already *less preferable*:

```
?- arg(2, v(a,x), x).
true.

?- arg(2, Head, x).
ERROR: arg/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Comment: Thanks, got it! The same idea came to me 5 minutes later. :D

Comment: Nope, seriously. I simply needed a break from programming. :D